# Including a SQL file within a SQL query

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

In Oracle SQL Developer, is there any way to include a SQL file within a SQL query? Like the command `\include{myfile.tex}` in LaTeX.

Example:

- `file1.sql` contains `FROM my_table;`
- `file2.sql` contains `SELECT * \include{file1.sql}`

Executing `file2.sql` from Oracle SQL Developer should be equivalent to executing `SELECT * FROM my_table;`.

Comment: In all my life, you're the very first person I've seen use a TeX example to demonstrate what they're looking for.

Comment: @EvanCarroll well you look quite young on your profile picture :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are to features of sqlplus (and maybe of SqlDeveloper)
that you can use to mimic the behaviour you want.

This is the [START command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1210918)

and the [variable substitution](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIFHGB) feature.

We want to execute

```
SQLPLUS> select *
  2  from dual;
```

which results in

```
D
-
X
```

We  now implement the requested files in the following way

file1.sql:

```
@file2.sql
select *
&FROM_CLAUSE
/
```

file2.sql

```
define FROM_CLAUSE='from dual'
```

this  gives the sqlplus output

```
SQLPLUS> @file1
old   2: &FROM_CLAUSE
new   2: from dual

D
-
X
```

sqlplus shows the variables and their values. You can suppress it by setting the property VERIFY to OFF

```
SQLPLUS> set VERIFY OFF
SQLPLUS> @file1.sql

D
-
X
```

You can redefine the FROM_CLAUSE variable and use it as shown in file3.sql

```
set verify off

@file2.sql
select *
&FROM_CLAUSE
/

@file4.sql
select *
&FROM_CLAUSE
/
```

file4.sql

```
define FROM_CLAUSE='from dual , -
dual b'
```

the define clause can be spread over more then  one line by ending each line by a minus '-' character. But sqlplus will  join it to one line. I now no way to assign a multiline block to a variable.

This results in

```
SQLPLUS> @file3

D
-
X


D D
- -
X X
```

Here is another example

file5.sql

```
@file6.sql
select &TABLE_ALIAS..dummy
&FROM_CLAUSE
&WHERE_CLAUSE
&GROUP_CLAUSE
&ORDER_CLAUSE
/
```

file6.sql

```
define TABLE_ALIAS=a
define FROM_CLAUSE='from dual a, -
dual b'
define WHERE_CLAUSE=' '
define GROUP_CLAUSE=' '
define ORDER_CLAUSE='order by 1'
```

this gives

```
SQLPLUS> @file5

D
-
X
```

Here you see that the suffix '.sql' can be omitted in sqlplus. If a variable that represents a line should contains no value the it should be at least a blank, an empty string will raise an error in the sql statement

```
SQLPLUS> define ORDER_BY=''
SQLPLUS> select  *
  2  from dual
  3  &ORDER_BY;
SP2-0341:
line overflow during variable substitution (>3000 characters at line 3)
```

A dot character '.' terminates a variable name, so if you want a dot after a variable name you must add an additional dot.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL*Plus, execute external scripts using @filename (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1210918).

This also works in SQL Developer, just be aware of the differences between relative & absolute directory.

Comment: that doesn't answer his question....